# Angular2 rxjs http.request.catch has strange behaviour for some http errors

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, rxjs, observable

My http service does not catch correctly some http errors.
The catch method has 2 different response objects ( see below ).

```
private fireRequest(request: Request): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.request(request)
    .switchMap((response: Response) => {
        const responseData = response.json() || [];
        return Observable.of(responseData);
    })
    .catch((response: Response) => {
        const res2 = response.json();
        // filters http errors from status 0 errors
        if (response.status && response.status > 0) {
            const res = response.json();
            return Observable.of<any>(res);
        }
        const unexpectedNetworkError = new 
              Error('commons.unexpected_network');
        return Observable.throw(unexpectedNetworkError);
    })
}
```

Strange error behaviour.
( even in chrome network tab i do not see the http body )

```
// catch 404 error
{ 
  headers: Headers,
  ok: false,
  status: 0,
  statusText : "",
  type : 3,
  url : null,
  _body : ProgressEvent
}
```

Correct error behaviour

```
// catch 401 error
{ 
  headers: Headers,
  ok: false,
  status: 401,
  statusText : "Unauthorized",
  type : 2,
  url : http://api.service/users,
  _body : { // json body}
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi, I found out the problem regards the browser an its CORS behaviour and my backend. When you call a non existing ruote, the browser sends a preflight request (options) and my be returns a 404 with error details in the body. However  the browser returns a generic error with http status code 0 without the actual payload. 
The second call is never made.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the elaborate answer! I also found a similar issue on mine which was related to CORS as well, but the issue for me was that my middleware was broken in the API. Once I fixed that I was good to go, but that did illuminate that other issue as well though. The other issue for me was that I WAS getting the original request made, because I could see the valid response in the network tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the problem regards the browser and its CORS behaviour.

**a) Succefull call**

```
BROWSER                  SERVER
    | ------ preflight ---> |
    | <-- allow GET, PUT -- |
    | ------- GET req ----> |
    | <------ GET res ----- |
```

**b) Failed call with backed response 404 instead of 200**

```
BROWSER                SERVER
    | ---- preflight ----> |
    | <------ 404 -------- |
    |                      |
    |                      |
```

**c) No intenet connection, no response from server**

```
BROWSER                SERVER
    | ---- preflight ----> X
    |                      |
    |                      |
    |                      |
```

Whenever you make an api call to a non existing ruote, the browser sends a preflight request (b).

Depening on your backend error handling strategy you could receive:

**1)** Http 404 code with error details in the body
In this case the browser returns a generic error with http status code 0 without the actual server's payload. The second call is never made because there is no sense in doing it since the preflight went wrong.

**2)** Http 200 code for the preflight and 404 for the actual call.
In this case everything works fine.

The problem remains if there is no internet connection.