# Angular2/Rxjs: 'catch' on observable giving ProgressEvent instead of json from response

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my `HttpServive`, I have shared http methods that will handle starting/ending the loading bar, setting the proper headers for JWT, and so on.

All is fine, but now I am trying to add some logic in the `catch` to check the response in the event of a non-200 status code (such as 401), so that I can do something and then re-make the failed request.

The problem is, the response I get back in the event of a non-200 status code is not accessible from that `catch` for whatever reason.

For instance, this is the code:

```
// ...

return this.http[method](url, options || defaultOptions)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()) // <--- gives JSON from response
    .catch((error: any)) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.json()); // <--- should give JSON from response, but gives ProgressEvent instead
        return Observable.throw(error.json()); // also gives ProgressEvent when I 'subscribe' to the observable
    })
    .finally(() => {
        this.loadingBarService.complete();
    });
```

The `console.log(error)` outputs the error of type `Response`; The `console.log(error.json())` outputs some data of type `ProgressEvent`.

Why am I getting a ProgressEvent, instead of the JSON sent from the non-200 status code response?

This is the `ProgressEvent`:

```
{
    bubbles: false,
    cancelBubbles: false,
    cancelable: false,
    composed: false,
    currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest,
    defaultPrevented: false,
    eventPhase: 0,
    isTrusted: true,
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    path: Array(0),
    returnValue: true,
    srcElement: XMLHttpRequest,
    target: XMLHttpRequest,
    timeStamp: 1234.115,
    total: 0,
    type: "error",
    __proto__: ProgressEvent
}
```

As you can see, the `ProgressEvent` is not my response. My response is a JSON object with just one `error` property, which contains a message and a status. This is just wrong, why don't I get my response?

Comment: do u use Http service from Angular or something lese?

Comment: The `HttpService` is custom made by me, and it leverages the `Http` service provided by `@angular/http`. Hence `this.http` in the example.

Comment: so i think this event is comming from there. please post it here.

Comment: This person has a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591307/angular2-rxjs-http-request-catch-has-strange-behaviour-for-some-http-errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 rxjs http.request.catch has strange behaviour for some http errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591307/angular2-rxjs-http-request-catch-has-strange-behaviour-for-some-http-errors)

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue working on a spa project based on Angular and Asp.Net Core.

If it is the same issue it should have depend from the missing of CORS headers in the http response that client receives from server. 
This response violates the browser CORS policy and most likely depends from not handled run time errors in the server.

Even catching all errors and putting into returning response some info and http status, Angular, when occur CORS constraints violations, doesn't allow to have access to any info of the response, not even the http status, and so it produces the "empty" response:

```
Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …} headers : Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)} ok : false status : 0 statusText : "" type : 3 url : null..
```

I solved this issue putting CORS headers into the response returned by the ASp.Net Core api server to the client in this way:

```
   app.UseExceptionHandler(appError => {
                appError.Run(async context => {

                    var _config = ServiceProviderFactory.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppConfigurations>();

                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", $"{_config.AngularSiteUrl}");
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access-control-allow-origin,authorization,content-type");

                    var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (contextFeature != null) {

                        var ex = contextFeature.Error;

                        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                        var _logger = sp.GetService<IGenericRepository<Log>>();

                        _logger.AddAndSave(new Log {
                            Description = "Exception not handled occurred",
                            Reason = ex.ToString(),
                            Type = "Error"
                        });

                         await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
                            Status = context.Response.StatusCode,
                            Message = "Internal Server Error."
                        }));
                    }
                });
```

The code has to be put into in the `Configure` method of `Startup` class.

I hope that it could be of some help.